# Oracle Import Error in 11GR2, ORA-39082 objects creating with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11GR2 version. I exported a dump successfully using the following command, At the time of exporting I didn't see any error  amd everything went well.

```
expdp DBCOPY/DBCOPY@EAMSB1 DIRECTORY=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=dbcopy.dmp logfile=dbcopy.log schemas=DBCOPY
```

And I tried to import it using impdp, for another user in the same database instance, by creating another user(For testing at my end)

```
impdp directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=DBCOPY.dmp FROMUSER=DBCOPY TRANSFORM=oid:n TOUSER=MADHU log=testlog9.log ignore=y remap_tablespace ={OBS_DATA:DATA_7I}
```

Here it shows

> Import is unsuccessful with following errors

Please suggest me any problem with my impdb or expdb commands. I while importing I am getting some errros like tablespace OBS_DATA not found. So I tried remap_tablespace attribute.

Errors in log file

```
processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7SPNDMA" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7WZCOSL" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7OZOCST" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7OZLCOLTOTAL" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7OZOCSTTOTAL" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7REPJZACOS" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7REPJZPBCS" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7REPJZCOSL" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_FUNCTION:"MADHU "."O7REPJYACOS" created with compilation warnings
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_PROCEDURE:"MADHU "."DELETEDTBL" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_PROCEDURE:"MADHU "."SETFORCED" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_PROCEDURE:"MADHU "."O7PNODMA" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type ALTER_PROCEDURE:"MADHU "."O7WOCOST" created with compilation warnings
```

Is there any problem with import and export commands? At the end of the log file i can't see the message

```
Import terminated successfully
```

Instead it is giving following message

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 35 error(s) at 23:35:34
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database export contains stored procedures and functions. They couldn't be compiled when you imported them again.

In SQLplus (and many other tools), you can run `SHOW ERRORS` to investigate the specific errors, eg.:

```
SHOW ERRORS FUNCTION MADHU.O7SPNDMA
```

Since you have imported the data with a different user and possibly on a different database instance altogether, the new user might not have the same rights to access tables and other PL/SQL packages, there might be hard-coded user/schema names in the code or synonyms could be missing to successfully compile the functions and procedures.

`SHOW ERRORS` will tell. If you need more support, you can add the output of `SHOW ERRORS` to your question.

Comment: I would just add that debugging might be easier with Oracle SQL Developer than just using SQLPlus.

Answer (score 1):

From which database was the export taken? If it was was 10g, you might need the fix for bug 5581731.

Comment: The dump has taken from the same database version oracle11gr2